# Perl Gtk2::Window->list_toplevels

Tags: perl, gtk2

I'm using Perl Gtk2, and I want to see the list of open toplevel windows, using:

```
my @WL = Gtk2::Window->list_toplevels;
print STDOUT "TOP_WINDOWS:\n @WL\n";
TOP_WINDOWS: 
Gtk2::Window=HASH(0x23a4040) Gtk2::Window=HASH(0x23b5628) Gtk2::Window=HASH(0x1ca6238)

When I dump this list:
print STDOUT "DUMPER:\n", Dumper (@WL);
... it yields this:
DUMPER:
$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'Gtk2::Window' );
$VAR2 = bless( {}, 'Gtk2::Window' );
$VAR3 = bless( {}, 'Gtk2::Window' );
```

How do I process the above bless objects/value?
I'm looking to get the name (or some kind of unique indicator) of each of the top_level window.

**FOLLOW-UP QUSTION:**
The following doesn't work for "state" when I have additional widgets inside the toplevel - I got to believe I'm simply missing something here!

```
sub SM_callback ()
{
 my ($button, $data) = @_;

 my $DS       = $$data[0];
 my $hostname = $$data[1]; 

 state $DW;
 if ( ! $DW )
 { 
  $DW = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
  $DW->set_default_size(400, 200);
  $DW->set_title($hostname);

  my $VB = Gtk2::VBox->new( 0, 0 );
  $DW->add($VB);

  my $TB = Gtk2::TextBuffer->new();
  $TB->set_text($hostname);

  my $TV = Gtk2::TextView->new_with_buffer($TB);

  my $SW = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new( undef, undef );
  $SW->add($TV);

  $VB->add($SW);

  $DW->show_all;
 }
 else
 {
  $DW->present;
 }

}
```

Comment: Did you get the number of toplevels?

Comment: Yes, but by virtue of the 3 returned values of @WL ... but I want to see (or assume) there's "hidden" data that will let me identify each of the 3 toplevel windows - I need to somehow process these "blessed" values.

Comment: Note that Gtk2 is deprecated. I would port the code to Gtk3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my final solution:

By looping thru the list_toplevels in call_back funct, and if top_level window is already opened (or minimized) via checking get_name, then present it, otherwise create the new top_level window (and set_name for future checking).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# PURPOSE: Trying to determine how to recognize which toplevel window
#          is open to avoid opening same toplevel window muliple times.

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say state);
use Data::Dumper;
use Gtk2 -init;

#######################################################################
sub BN_callback 
{
 my ($button, $dataref) = @_;
 my $widget_name = $$dataref[0];

 my @open_TLW = Gtk2::Window->list_toplevels;

 foreach my $w ( @open_TLW )
 {
  my $open_name = $w->get_name;
  if ( $open_name eq $widget_name )
  {
   $w->present;
   return;
  } 
 }

 my $DW = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
    $DW->set_default_size(400, 200);
    $DW->set_title($widget_name." sigtest_file");
    $DW->set_name($widget_name);
    $DW->show_all;
}
#######################################################################

my $TL = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
   $TL->set_default_size(400, 200);
   $TL->set_position('center');
   $TL->set_name('Main_Window');
   $TL->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub { Gtk2->main_quit });
   $TL->show_all;

my $VB = Gtk2::VBox->new( 0, 0 );

$TL->add($VB);

my @BN = qw/BUTTON1 BUTTON2/;
foreach my $bn ( @BN )
{
 my $BT = Gtk2::Button->new($bn);
    $BT->set_name($bn); 
    $BT->signal_connect(clicked =>  \&BN_callback, [$bn]);

 $VB->add($BT);
}

$TL->show_all;
Gtk2->main;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `list_toplevels` method returns the list of [Gtk2::Window](https://metacpan.org/release/GTHYNI/Gtk2-Perl-0.08/view/Gtk2/Window.pm) (or [here](https://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Window.html)) objects.  Browse the docs to see the kinds of methods/idetifiers that are available for toplevel windows, what you seek.

Developed from the synopsis of [Gtk2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk2)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Gtk2 -init;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_default_size(400, 200);
$window->set_position('center');
$window->set_name('main');
$window->set_title('Main Window');
my $button = Gtk2::Button->new('Quit');
$button->signal_connect(clicked => sub { Gtk2->main_quit });
$window->add($button);
$window->show_all;

my $win2 = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$win2->set_default_size(100, 200);
$win2->set_name('side');
$win2->set_title('== side window ==');
my $bt2 = Gtk2::Button->new('Hello');
$win2->add($bt2);
$win2->show_all;

my @tl_wins = Gtk2::Window->list_toplevels;
for my $w (@tl_wins) {
    say "name:  ", $w->get_name;
    say "title: ", $w->get_title;
}

Gtk2->main;
```

The methods `set_name` and `get_name` are inherited from the class [Gtk::Widget](https://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Widget.html), further up in the hierarchy.  It is common in such a complex hierarchy to find needed functionality in parent classes.

This prints their names and titles, as a demo.  There are other identifiers and properties, depending on what you need this for.

Note, since these are bindings for the C libraries the docs are sometimes scattered and incomplete.  Searching around for extra documentation is probably a good idea.

---

The purpose of this, as explained in comments

> ...from a frame's [button's] signal_connect("clicked"), i open a toplevel window containing a TextView and ScrolledWindow and successfully display data. But if I click on that same frame, it opens another duplicate toplevel instance. I rather either bring to focus the open one, or delete the original and open a new toplevel - basically only ever have 1 instance.

Here is one way for that

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say state);
 
use Gtk2 -init;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_default_size(400, 200);
$window->set_position('center');
$window->set_title('Main Window');
$window->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub { Gtk2->main_quit });
$window->show_all;

my $w2 = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$w2->set_default_size(300, 300);
$w2->set_title('== side ==');
my $bt2 = Gtk2::Button->new('Bring up window');

$bt2->signal_connect(clicked => sub { 
    state $subwin;
    if (not $subwin) { 
        $subwin = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
        $subwin->set_default_size(200, 200);
        $subwin->set_position('center-on-parent');
        my $bt = Gtk2::Button->new('say "hi"');
        $bt->signal_connect(clicked => sub { say "hi" });
        $subwin->add($bt);
        $subwin->show_all;
    }
    else { $subwin->present }
});
$w2->add($bt2);
$w2->show_all;

Gtk2->main;
```

(I removed some unneeded pieces from the initial example)

To test, once the "side" window is clicked and a new window is created, move it and hide it behind another window.  Clicking again re-`present`s the window.

---

Corrections for the code in the "*FOLLOW-UP QUSTION*", which has been added to the question:

- That callback is written with a [prototype](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes), requiring no arguments for the subroutine (the empty `()` after the sub's name).  I take it that prototypes aren't needed here and that `()` is there in error, but it does mess up passed arguments -- so remove those `()`.
- Further down in the sub, the `TextBuffer` is given the `$hostname`, presumably intended for the window title, and not data that seems to be intended for scrolled text, seemingly `$DS`

Then I add that callback to the `say "hi"` button, calling it after `hi` is printed.  (I need to remove `$button` from the argument list if it's used this way since it's then not really a callback and the button object doesn't get passed to it.)  I make up some data for it and it all works.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252708/discussion-on-answer-by-zdim-perl-gtk2window-list-toplevels); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.